# How self reference class in Python in class member variables (not known syntax)?

Tags: python-2.7

I am learned Python some years ago but I do not know how to reference class as self.

See my problem:

```
class SomeClassReference(object):
  def __init__(self, reference):
    self.reference = reference

class MyClass(object):
  # MyClass is not defined - how to solve it?
  a = SomeClassReference(reference = MyClass)
```

Is it possible to do such self reference in Python what syntax I need to use to initialize **class member** with **class**. I use Python frequently but has no idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```py
class Point(object):
  ZERO = None
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
Point.ZERO = Point(0,0)
```

ZERO in the class definition is not needed but I'm using it because my IDE is not able to find the class variable for code completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a *setter method* (`setReference`):

```
class SomeClassReference(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reference = None

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = SomeClassReference()

    def setReference(self):
        self.a.reference = MyClass
```

Comment: It is not answer. `self.a` is **instance member** not **class member**. `MyClass.a` will be undefined.